# ¿Cómo imprimir valores de listas definidos por rangos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucle-for

En mi código tengo:

```
listaTotal = ["Carros","Honda", "Nissan", "Aviones","Boeing777", "Airbus340", "Boeing757", "Barcos","Boats"]
```

Y lo que quiero obtener al final en consola es:

```
Carros
Honda
Nissan
Aviones
Boeing777
Airbus340
Boeing757
Barcos
Boats
```

Lo cual es la palabra `Carros` seguido de las marcas de carros, luego `Aviones` seguido de las marcas de aviones, y por ultimo `Botes` seguido de las marcas de botes.

Lo que se me ha ocurrido a mi es crear un método con el cual extraigo las palabras `Carros, Aviones, Barcos`, con lo cual dichas palabras las alojo en la lista `separadores` de manera que dicha lista me queda como `separadores = ["Carros", "Aviones", "Barcos"]`.
Luego tengo un método el cual me cuenta el índice en los cuales encuentra las palabras `["Carros", "Aviones", "Barcos"]`, dichos índices los saco en base a `listaTotal`, de manera que los guardo en la lista `indicesDeSeparadores` y en dicha lista agrego de ultimo la longitud de `listaTotal` por lo tanto la lista queda como `indicesDeSeparadores = [0, 3, 7, len(listaTotal)]#>>>[0, 3, 7, 9]`.
Ya teniendo `indicesDeSeparadores` con sus respectivos valores procedo a pensar en que podría definir rangos, y que por ejemplo tomando como base `listaTotal` supongamos que imprimo `Carros`, entonces las marcas de carros se encuentran en el rango de `(0,3)`, y con `Aviones`, las marcas de aviones se encuentran en el rango de `(3,7)` y `Barcos` en el rango de `(7,len(listaTotal))`, dichos rangos los definí en base a `indicesDeSeparadores`.

Los métodos que menciono arriba con los cuales saque ciertas listas no los pongo en el código total ya que seria extenso, por lo que solo pondré las listas ya definidas. El código junto y seguido de lo que intente hacer es:

```
listaTotal = ["Carros","Honda", "Nissan", "Aviones","Boeing777", "Airbus340", "Boeing757", "Barcos","Boats"]

separadores = ["Carros", "Aviones", "Barcos"]

indicesDeSeparadores = [0, 3, 7, len(listaTotal)]#>>>[0, 3, 7, 9]

for i in range(len(separadores)):
    for j in range(indicesDeSeparadores[i], indicesDeSeparadores[i+1], 1):
        print(separadores[i],'\n',listaTotal[j])
```

Con dicho código lo que obtuve en pantalla fue:

```
Carros 
 Carros
Carros
 Honda
Carros
 Nissan
Aviones
 Aviones
Aviones
 Boeing777
Aviones
 Airbus340
Aviones
 Boeing757
Barcos
 Barcos
Barcos
 Boats
```

Lo cual quizá se acerca un poquito a la salida que quiero, mas sin embargo me quedo con que no es lo que exactamente quiero.

A mi esta manera es la única que se me ocurrió, por lo que si a alguien se le ocurre otra manera de hacer estaría bien también, eso si, teniendo en cuenta que todo es en base a la lista `listaTotal`.
También tengo un método el cual me clasifica solo los transportes `listaTransportes = ["Honda", "Nissan", "Boeing777", "Airbus340", "Boeing757","Boats"]`, lo menciono por si a alguien se le ocurre algo mas conforme a dicha lista también.
Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, de antemano gracias!

Comment: Pero no entiendo... Si la salida que buscas es la primera que has escrito ¿no basta con imprimir la lista en el orden en que viene? A fin de cuentas, en la propia lista vienen los coches tras la palabra "Coches", los aviones tras la palabra "Aviones", etc. ¿O quizás buscas separar en tres listas los coches, aviones y barcos? (en vez de imprimirlo sin más como mostraste en la primera salida)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Python se trabaja mejor con diccionarios y listas. Esto de andar jugando con indices es propio de lenguajes del pasado ... :-)

En esta solución se construye un diccionario cuya llave es la categoría (Carros, Aviones, Barcos) y cuyo valor es la lista de vehículos en ella.

Suponemos que `listaTotal` es una lista que comienza con una categoría ("Carros"), seguidos de sus elementos, otra categoría, sus elementos, etc.

Recorremos la lista y cada vez que detectamos una categoría, añadimos una nueva entrada al diccionario `final`, poniendo como valor una lista vacía.

Al seguir iterando en `listaTotal`, si no es una categoría, añadimos el elemento a la lista de la última categoría encontrada.

```
listaTotal = ["Carros","Honda", "Nissan", "Aviones","Boeing777", "Airbus340", "Boeing757", "Barcos","Boats"]
separadores = ["Carros", "Aviones", "Barcos"]

final = {}
for elemento in listaTotal:
    if elemento in separadores:
        separador = elemento
        final[separador] = []
    else:
        final[separador].append(elemento)

for k, v in final.items():
    print(k, "=", v)
```

produce:

```
Carros = ['Honda', 'Nissan']
Aviones = ['Boeing777', 'Airbus340', 'Boeing757']
Barcos = ['Boats']
```

**Edición**

Si sólo se trata de imprimir, sin necesidad de crear una estructura de datos para uso posterior, hay una solución más simple:

```
listaTotal = ["Carros","Honda", "Nissan", "Aviones","Boeing777", "Airbus340", "Boeing757", "Barcos","Boats"]
separadores = ["Carros", "Aviones", "Barcos"]
for elemento in listaTotal:
    if elemento in separadores:
        print(elemento)
    else:
        print("  ", elemento)
```

produce:

```
Carros
   Honda
   Nissan
Aviones
   Boeing777
   Airbus340
   Boeing757
Barcos
   Boats
```

Answer (score 1):

La mejor solución es la que te dan en otras respuestas, es decir, usar un diccionario para almacenar tus datos, o bien convertir tu lista a un diccionario.

No obstante, por responder a la pregunta originalmente planteada **"Cómo imprimir valores de listas definidos por rangos"**, te daré una técnica útil.

Tu lista `indicesDeSeparadores` contiene `[0, 3, 7, 9]`. Cada elemento y el siguiente definen un rango. Es decir, quieres los rangos `[(0,3), (3,7), (7,9)]`. Si te fijas esos rangos salen de emparejar uno con uno los elementos de la lista `[0, 3, 7, 9]` con los de la lista `[3, 7, 9]`, que es la misma lista omitiendo el primer elemento.

Python tiene una función para emparejar listas, que es `zip()`, así que usando `zip(indicesDeSeparadores, indicesDeSeparadores[1:])` obtienes justo las parejas que necesitas. Iterando sobre esas parejas y usando sus valores como parte de un *slice*, `listaTotal[inicio:fin]`, puedes ir extrayendo los subrangos que te interesan. Imprimirlos en vertical es cuestión de juntarlos con retornos de carro (`"\n".join()`).

A pesar de la larga explicación el código se reduce a un par de líneas. He añadido un `print()` adicional para separar los grupos en la salida (de otro modo, el resultado sería equivalente a imprimir sencillamente la lista, que sería mucho más simple).

```
for inicio, fin in zip(indicesDeSeparadores, indicesDeSeparadores[1:]):
  print("\n".join(listaTotal[inicio:fin]))
  print()
```

Resultado:

```
Carros
Honda
Nissan

Aviones
Boeing777
Airbus340
Boeing757

Barcos
Boats
```

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te han dicho, lo correcto en tu caso sería trabajar con un diccionario con la siguiente estructura:

```
listaTotal = {'Carros':['Honda','Nissan'],'Aviones':['Boeing777','Airbus340','Boeing757'],'Barcos':['Boats']}
```

En ese caso con:

```
for k in listaTotal.keys():
    print(k,*listaTotal[k], sep='\n')
```

Obtienes la salida que buscas:

```
Carros
Honda
Nissan
Aviones
Boeing777
Airbus340
Boeing757
Barcos
Boats
```

Esta estructura es mejor porque podrías por ejemplo imprimir todas las categorías, o los elementos de alguna de ellas, etc:

```
print(listaTotal.keys())  #Devuelve= dict_keys(['Carros', 'Aviones', 'Barcos'])
print(listaTotal['Carros'])  #Devuelve= ['Honda', 'Nissan']
```

Si por cualquier motivo no puedes utilizar un diccionario, puedes imprimir la lista entera uno por uno con:

```
listaTotal = ["Carros","Honda", "Nissan", "Aviones","Boeing777", "Airbus340", "Boeing757", "Barcos","Boats"]
print(*listaTotal,sep='\n')
```

Que te daría la misma salida:

```
Carros
Honda
Nissan
Aviones
Boeing777
Airbus340
Boeing757
Barcos
Boats
```